# Rvm versus Mysql

Tags: mysql, path, console, rvm, profile

Did the fact of adding rvm path to the .profile disable the launch of Mysql from the command line. 
I'm asking it because i have install the rmv lately and since then I can't get access to the data base via the `$ mysql`.
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the installation instructions, then no, RVM should not break mysql. RVM appends itself to your $PATH variable. It does not replace it. (Otherwise, all the system commands would fail)

Comment: here is what i have on the .profile .
> export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
> #export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
but i don't know why it's not working